# If two sequences converge to the same point, does their difference get smaller?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Suppose $a(t), b(t) \to a$ as $ t \to 0^+$. Here the convergence is in a Hilbert space $H$.

We have for some $t$ that $$|a(t)-b(t)|_H \leq \epsilon$$ for some $\epsilon$. Does it follow that
$$|a(s)-b(s)|_H \leq \epsilon$$ also whenever $s \leq t$?

One may expect this since as you shrink time both sequence get closer to the same point.

Comment: Well, no, of course. If $t$ is one of the $t$-s such that $\forall s\le t, \lvert a(s)-a\rvert\le\frac\epsilon 2\wedge \lvert b(s)-a\rvert\le\frac\epsilon 2$ yes. Otherwise (or if an analogous conditions doesn't occur), it might not happen. Look at the case of real sequences: when $\lim_n a_n=L$, is it always true that $\lvert a_n-L\rvert\le\varepsilon$ implies $\forall m\ge n,\ \lvert a_m-L\rvert\le\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: However, it is true that $\lim_{t\to 0^+} \lvert a(t)-b(t)\rvert=0$ (which is weaker than what you asked in the question and, possibly, in the title).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli thanks